# Converting PDF to PDF/A? (for embedding fonts)

Tags: pdf, script, fonts, printing, embedded-fonts

How do I convert PDF to PDF/A? - No preference of operating system to run the script or program.

(this is for printing directly on my printer; however the printer requires print formats with fonts included)

Comment: What program are you using the generate the files? Many provide an option.

Comment: Yeah, LibreOffice suite is what I use to create my PDF/A files; but most of the PDFs I want to print I get online; in only PDF format…

Comment: In that case, you may have some luck with pdftk. I'm not sure if it can do this, but it's a pretty powerful all-round piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I was looking for using an open-source PDF printer by the name "[PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)".

[image: options screen]

Answer (score 0):

your best bet may be [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (Postscript interpreter for PDF), but I can't tell you exactly how to pull it off, so you will have to do some research. you may want to start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659147/how-to-use-ghostscript-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-or-pdf-x)

you can try a web service like [this one](http://createpdf.neevia.com/pdfconvert/) (2mb limit though), and almost all commercial editors allow you to save in PDF/A in either the Save As ... feature or the document properties.

DocuPrinter Pro:  http://neevia.com/products/dppro/

Acrobat Pro:      http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/05/using-save-as-to-to-conform-to-pdfa/

Solid Documents 'PDF to PDF/A' : http://www.soliddocuments.com/convert/PDF-to-PDF-A/303/11

Answer (score 0):

Embedding all fonts in a PDF is **not** the same thing as having a file that complies with the PDF/A (ISO 19005) set of standards. Compliance with PDF/A requires many more features of PDF to be enabled (or disabled) accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I know. However for this specific problem of not being able to print, whether it's PDF/A compliant or not isn't the issue; what I need to be able to do is print in same font as is on screen.